# Import files with size more than 0 kb from location and merge in R

Tags: r, file, hadoop, dataframe, hdfs

I Have multiple hdfs files in a file path and need to import and merge in all in 1 dataframe in R.
Currently using below statement but in this, if there is any file with 0kb, it get failed and every time I copied files from hadoop, it always have 0kb files.

Please suggest a way to import and merge files with size more than 0kb.

currently using statement (which have issues in merging files with 0kb).

```
library(data.table)  
t = setwd("/filepath/1/")
files <- list.files(path = t,pattern = "")
temp <- lapply(files, fread, sep=",")
data <- rbindlist( temp )
```

Comment: you can use `file.info` to get their size first and keep only those of more than 0kb

Comment: Do you get the error in the `rbindlist` command? Id so, you could also first filter out empty entries from the `temp` object before merging it...

Comment: thanks you both. done as mentioned. and this can be by R only, so easly, thanks to R also.

files <- file.info(list.files(path = t,pattern = "", full.names=TRUE))
files = rownames(files)[files$size > 0]